# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in com.services.dll occurred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm a beginner and Learning ASP.NET MVC, My application was working perfectly I've learned about Singleton but after including Singleton pattern in my application I'm getting an exception on my ProductService class which is in com.service project.I have a solution and in that solution, I've 4 projects with these names com.Entities,com.database,com.services,com.web

I've tried to check Use Managed Compatibility Code in Tools -> Options -> Use ManagedCode

com.service: Getting Exception at public static ProductService Instance

```
public class ProductService
```

{

```
public  static ProductService Instance
    {
        get 
        {
             if (Instance == null) instance = new ProductService();
             return instance;
        }
    }

    private static ProductService instance { get; set; }

    private ProductService() {}

    CContext context = new CContext();

    public List<Product> GetProducts()
    { 
         return context.Products.Include(x => x.Category).ToList(); 
    }
```

}

com.web: controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     var prod = ProductService.Instance.GetProduct(id);
     UpdateProductViewModels editModel = new UpdateProductViewModels ();
     editModel.ID = prod.ID;
     editModel.Name = prod.Name;
     editModel.CategoryID = prod.Category != null ? prod.Category.ID : 0;
     editModel.CategoryList = CategoryService.Instance.GetCategories();
     return PartialView(editModel);
    }
```

com.Entities

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool isFeatured { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }
}
```

namespace com.Entities

```
public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are referencing Instance instead of the local member instance.

It's typically good practice to put something like an underscore in front of the local member to make it more easily identified.

The getter in Instance should look like this:

```
            if (instance == null) instance = new ProductService();
            return instance;
```

I would recommend renaming it to _instance to avoid confusion.

HTH

wazdev

Comment: Thanks You, it worked. I was not referencing correctly. Now it's working.